# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "boost-for-react-native"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

In my react-native project, I have this dependency of "boost-for-react-native" and installing it like this:

```
  pod 'boost-for-react-native', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/master/boost-for-react-native.podspec'
```

It was working fine lately. I am not sure what changed but I am now unable to install pods. I am getting this error when I run pod install

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "boost-for-react-native":
  In Podfile:
    Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`) was resolved to 2018.10.22.00, which depends on
      boost-for-react-native

    React-jsi (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi`) was resolved to 0.61.5, which depends on
      boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)

    boost-for-react-native (from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/master/boost-for-react-native.podspec`)
```

I have tried removing node_modules, deleting podfile.lock, deintegrate pod. I also tried upgrading the deployment version in podfile and app targets to 11.0. But I still get the above error.

I will really appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: I got the fix from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77738910/2033377

Answer (score 8):

This could be because of pod cache.

Try this:

1. Delete cocoa pods cache: `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`
2. Delete the `Pods` folder and the `Podfile.lock` usually located in
   `<project_root>/ios`.
3. Reinstall pods: `pod update`

Comment: Already tried all these steps. Deintegrated pods, deleted podfile.lock, pod update.

Answer (score 1):

For workaround solution. You don't need to download the tar.bz2. And move to node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs.

Only change line

```
spec.source = { :http => 'https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2',
:sha256 => 'f0397ba6e982c4450f27bf32a2a83292aba035b827a5623a14636ea583318c41' }
```

to

```
spec.source = { :http => 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.76.0/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2',
:sha256 => 'f0397ba6e982c4450f27bf32a2a83292aba035b827a5623a14636ea583318c41' }
```

In file node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec

I think jfrog close their server. You may need to change 76 if you use another version

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution or hack :)

As the error indicates **Incompatible version** of boost-for-react-native, the link for podspec file has version 1.63.0-1.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/master/boost-for-react-native.podspec

But expected version was 1.63.0

To fix this, I forked the repository and edited the version to 1.63.0. Then did pod install and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My current react-native version is `0.60.5`

I change my podspec to:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/update-ios-platform-version/boost-for-react-native.podspec

And worked.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is to download the file and then source it from the local filesystem, rather than making a network call:

Download the tar.bz2 file from https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2

Move the (compressed) file to:

node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs

open: node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec

change the :http part of the spec.source key to:
:http => 'file:' + **dir** + '/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2'

run pod install

note: you may need to adjust the version of the boost package your project specifies.