# How can I get past installing Boost with React Native environment setup for iOS?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, boost, cocoapods

I am currently trying to start a project in React Native version 0.73, but I'm having an issue when I do `pod install` in the iOS directory, specifically with installing Boost version 1.83.0.

```
(node:66063) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
[Codegen] generating an empty RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
[Codegen] Found rncore
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec`
[Hermes] Using release tarball from URL: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native-artifacts/0.73.1/react-native-artifacts-0.73.1-hermes-ios-debug.tar.gz
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.73.1)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.73.1)
Installing Flipper (0.201.0)
Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.2.0.1)
Installing Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.10)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.5.0.5)
Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)
Installing FlipperKit (0.201.0)
Installing OpenSSL-Universal (1.1.1100)
Installing RCT-Folly (2022.05.16.00)
Installing RCTRequired (0.73.1)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.73.1)
Installing React (0.73.1)
Installing React-Codegen (0.73.1)
Installing React-Core (0.73.1)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.73.1)
Installing React-Fabric (0.73.1)
Installing React-FabricImage (0.73.1)
Installing React-ImageManager (0.73.1)
Installing React-Mapbuffer (0.73.1)
Installing React-NativeModulesApple (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTAppDelegate (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTFabric (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTText (0.73.1)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.73.1)
Installing React-callinvoker (0.73.1)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.73.1)
Installing React-debug (0.73.1)
Installing React-graphics (0.73.1)
Installing React-hermes (0.73.1)
Installing React-jserrorhandler (0.73.1)
Installing React-jsi (0.73.1)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.73.1)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.73.1)
Installing React-logger (0.73.1)
Installing React-nativeconfig (0.73.1)
Installing React-perflogger (0.73.1)
Installing React-rendererdebug (0.73.1)
Installing React-rncore (0.73.1)
Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.73.1)
Installing React-runtimescheduler (0.73.1)
Installing React-utils (0.73.1)
Installing ReactCommon (0.73.1)
Installing SocketRocket (0.6.1)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing boost (1.83.0)

[!] Error installing boost
Verification checksum was incorrect, expected 6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e, got 5e89103d9b70bba5c91a794126b169cb67654be2051f90cf7c22ba6893ede0ff
```

I have tried following a couple of blogs on how to set up React Native with an [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) chip with unsuccessful results: *[How to fix “pod install” error in React Native on Mac M1](https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/how-to-fix-pod-install-error-in-react-native-on-mac-m1-5d79dc52f7e8)*

Xcode Command Line tools: Xcode 14.3.1 
[Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js): 21.5.0 
macOS: Ventura 13.5

Comment: This seems to be related to the boost package itself. If you run `curl -sL https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.83.0/source/boost_1_83_0.tar.bz2 | shasum -a 256` on a Mac, you will get `5e89103d9b70bba5c91a794126b169cb67654be2051f90cf7c22ba6893ede0ff` back. This fails with that the `node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec` expects

Comment: I've submitted an issue here https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843

Comment: I solved this issue by following these steps [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738691/error-installing-boost-verification-checksum-was-incorrect-expected/77745446#77745446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738691/error-installing-boost-verification-checksum-was-incorrect-expected/77745446#77745446)

Answer (score 17):

Move to *node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs*.
In *boost.podspec*, only change the line

```
spec.source = { :http => 'https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.83.0/source/boost_1_83_0.tar.bz2',
:sha256 => '6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e' }
```

to

```
spec.source = { :http => 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.83.0/boost_1_83_0.tar.bz2',
:sha256 => '6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e' }
```

Maybe [JFrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository#Repository_managers) closed their server.

Comment: In addition, this code boost.podspec file

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue. For my side, it was an issue of the cache. I run the below commands one-by-one and am able to install the pod successfully,

In the project directory

```
npm cache clean --force --verbose
npm cache verify
npm install --force --verbose
```

In the iOS folder

```
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod repo update
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

for me its Work with platform :ios, 13.4

Answer (score 0):

This is related to an upstream issue with JFrog.

Rather than manually changing the checksum, a better approach is to use a mirror to download the package. This can be done in a repeatable way (compatible with [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Deploy_an_artefact_from_CI)) by creating a patch that is applied during `npm install`.

For instructions, see: *[Error installing boost Verification checksum was incorrect #843](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843#issuecomment-1872943124)*

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer from this question is also shown as the answer in a similar question.

Long story short, just change line in **node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77738910

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77740505/13493658