# Error installing Boost: Verification checksum was incorrect, expected

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, podfile

Error message:

> Verification checksum was incorrect, expected 6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e, got 5e89103d9b70bba5c91a794126b169cb67654be2051f90cf7c22ba6893ede0ff

Steps to reproduce

```
cd ios & pod install
```

Output:

```
React Native Version
0.73.1

Affected Platforms
Build - MacOS
```

[image]

The error occurred during React Native pod install.

Comment: we got the same error today as well.

Comment: Same, started today. 3 reports in the same day seems to suggest an upstream issue. An issue was opened here to track: https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843

Comment: started seeing this error today as well.

Comment: We found a temporary solution until the issue is resolved https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42109#issuecomment-1872922926

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The transcript as text can be seen in Stack Overflow question *[How can I get past installing Boost with React Native environment setup for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738285/how-to-get-past-installing-boost-with-react-native-environment-setup-for-ios)* (near *"Installing boost (1.83.0)"*).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) (it covers program text output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

This issue can occur when you have cached files that are corrupted or outdated. You can resolve this by running the following commands:

```
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: We found a temporary solution until the issue is resolved https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42109#issuecomment-1872922926

Answer (score 6):

There is a temporary solution on *[Error installing boost Verification checksum was incorrect #843](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843#issuecomment-1872943124)*.

Below are the steps which I followed to solve the Boost issue in React Native. I have 0.70.5 version of React Native in my project.

Step 1: delete folder *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)*, file *package-lock.json*, *pods* and *podfile.lock*

Step 2: Install *patch-package* (note: it also work with **yarn**)

```
npm install --save-dev patch-package postinstall-postinstall
```

Step 3: npm install

Step 4: Modify your **Modify boost.podspec:** in directory ***node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec*** (Note: if you have a version of React Native higher than 0.70, then change the Boost version to 1.83.0)

```
# Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = 'boost'
# change the version below line
  spec.version = '1.76.0'
  spec.license = { :type => 'Boost Software License', :file => "LICENSE_1_0.txt" }
  spec.homepage = 'http://www.boost.org'
  spec.summary = 'Boost provides free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries.'
  spec.authors = 'Rene Rivera'
https://
  spec.source = { :http => 'https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2',
                  :sha256 => 'f0397ba6e982c4450f27bf32a2a8b827c41' }

  # Pinning to the same version as React.podspec.
  spec.platforms = { :ios => '13.0', :tvos => '13.0' }
  spec.requires_arc = false

  spec.module_name = 'boost'
  spec.header_dir = 'boost'
  spec.preserve_path = 'boost'
end
```

The only changes are in these two lines, else they are the same:

```
spec.version = '1.76.0'
'https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2',
```

Step 5: run the below command to create a patch file based on your changes

```
npx patch-package react-native
```

Step 6: Modify your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

Step 7: run `npm install` and `pod install`. patch-package will automatically apply the patch to the *boost.podspec* file.

Below is my patch file which I created by the above command **react-native+0.70.5.patch**

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec b/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec
index 2f1fcc4..0f83c02 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec
@@ -10,11 +10,11 @@ Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
   spec.homepage = 'http://www.boost.org'
   spec.summary = 'Boost provides free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries.'
   spec.authors = 'Rene Rivera'
-  spec.source = { :http => 'https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2',
+  spec.source = { :http => 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.76.0/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2',
                   :sha256 => 'f0397ba6e982c4450f27bf37a5623a14636ea583318c41' }

   # Pinning to the same version as React.podspec.
-  spec.platforms = { :ios => '11.0', :tvos => '11.0' }
+  spec.platforms = { :ios => '13.0', :tvos => '13.0' }
   spec.requires_arc = false

   spec.module_name = 'boost'
```

Also update podfile iOS version to 13.0 minimum to support Boost 1.76.0. Otherwise you will run into this issue.

***Note***: The platform of the target `App_New` (iOS 12.4) may not be compatible with Boost (1.76.0) which has a minimum requirement of iOS 13.0 - tvOS 13.0.

```
platform: ios, '13.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the checksum in *boost.podspec* for now. Go to `node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`.

And replace it with:

```
# Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = 'boost'
  spec.version = '1.83.0'
  spec.license = { :type => 'Boost Software License', :file => "LICENSE_1_0.txt" }
  spec.homepage = 'http://www.boost.org'
  spec.summary = 'Boost provides free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries.'
  spec.authors = 'Rene Rivera'
  # Patched due to issue https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843
  spec.source = { :http => 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.83.0/boost_1_83_0.tar.bz2',
                  :sha256 => '6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e' }

  # Pinning to the same version as React.podspec.
  spec.platforms = min_supported_versions
  spec.requires_arc = false

  spec.module_name = 'boost'
  spec.header_dir = 'boost'
  spec.preserve_path = 'boost'
end
```

For your next install, you can create a patch for the package using patch-package. Instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a major problem with [JFrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository#Repository_managers). Here's a patch:

*[Error installing boost Verification checksum was incorrect #843](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843#issuecomment-1872943124)*

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue with React Native version 0.68.2 and managed to resolve it temporarily by following the suggestion below. Navigate to the 'boost.podspec' file and replace the link from:

'https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2'

to

'https://archives.boost.io/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2'

This adjustment helped me address the problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the changes as suggested in a previous answer, but it really didn't solve the problem. I made a patch of it. It doesn't solve the upstream problem, but it crashes the pod install, somehow.

```
⚠️  Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Failed to load 'boost' podspec: 
[!] Invalid `boost.podspec` file: undefined local variable or method `min_supported_versions' for Pod:Module.

 #  from /Users/agrittiwari/wishup/client-app/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec:17
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    # Pinning to the same version as React.podspec.
 >    spec.platforms = min_supported_versions
 #    spec.requires_arc = false
 #  -------------------------------------------


pod install --repo-update --ansi exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: This was due to the mismatch in spec version and url for that. 
The way is to check your boost podspec version, and replacing the url in http, for your podspec version, from sourceforge.net, instead of boostorg.

Comment: We found a temporary solution until the issue is resolved https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42109#issuecomment-1872922926

Answer (score 1):

Issue Description:
https://twitter.com/Kelset/status/1744307922065150097

Workaround:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42180

Answer (score 1):

This issue has now been addressed in React Native release [0.72.9](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.72.9) and [0.72.3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.73.2)

The underlying issue with the Boost dependency is detailed here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42110 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42180

The issue appears to have been caused by problems with the JFrog dependency repository.

The issue has been resolved by updates to the `boost.podspec` to pull it from `archives.boost.io` instead of `boostorg.jfrog.io/`

If you are using React Native 0.72.x then updating to 0.72.9 should resolve the issue. If you are using React Native 0.73.x then update to at least 0.73.2

Comment: Also patched on 0.71.15.
It looks like the react-native team is monitoring the situation to see what the final url ends up being.

Answer (score -1):

Run pod update in iOS directory and then start the project.