# React Native - Error at Installing CocoaPods dependencies, first project

Tags: react-native, macos, cocoapods

**EDIT:The whole problem was that the services were down. Today I was able to get a proper build in every version.**

I'm trying to install the necessary components on my computer to create React native projects, but I don't have a full knowledge of the macos environment. For 2 days I have been dealing with this problem. Finally I even reset my computer and:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native

I followed the steps in this address, but in the "Installing CocoaPods dependencies" step I get the following error:

> Installing CocoaPods dependencies  (this may take a few minutes)
> error (node:23862) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed.

In such a case, it is recommended to install pods manually with the "pod install" command in the "ios" folder. But when I do this, I get the following error:

> Error installing boost
> Verification checksum was incorrect, expected 6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e, got 5e89103d9b70bba5c91a794126b169cb67654be2051f90cf7c22ba6893ede0ff

I saw the following about this issue:

[Error installing boost: Verification checksum was incorrect, expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738691/error-installing-boost-verification-checksum-was-incorrect-expected)

https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843

They mention that this error has just started and that the server encountered the problem when validating the file.

**But I'm not sure if the error I'm getting in the "Installing CocoaPods dependencies" step is related to this.**

So I am open to your ideas.

I wanted to stand up my first react native project, so I followed the instructions on "react native dev" site but without success.

Comment: Have you tried, the answers suggested there? `pod cache clean --all
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod repo update
pod install`

Comment: I am not getting an error in react-native: "0.72.4", you could try downgrading to that version

Comment: @Mister_CK yes, i have. When I tried to install it with the "pod install" command after each cleanup, I got the checksum error I mentioned above.

I tried "0.72.4" version. I didn't get the same error but still got an error:
https://prnt.sc/KbLBVFPlq88S
(I am sending it as a screenshot so that it doesn't look bad)

I think this error may be due to the server problem I mentioned above. When this problem is solved, I think I will be able to build a low version project, but I am never sure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was that the services were down. Today I was able to get a proper build in every version. Thanks for everyone.