# react native cli. problem with Error installing boost

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to build new react native project. but is not working fine on IOS. when I try to install podfile these error came:

```
[!] Error installing boost
Verification checksum was incorrect, expected 6478edfe2f3305127cffe8caf73ea0176c53769f4bf1585be237eb30798c3b8e, got 5e89103d9b70bba5c91a794126b169cb67654be2051f90cf7c22ba6893ede0ff
```

to solve these problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get past installing boost with React Native environment setup for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738285/how-to-get-past-installing-boost-with-react-native-environment-setup-for-ios)

Comment: no even with these solution is not working fine.